# How to unescaped chars in airflow rendered template

Tags: airflow, custom-operator

I define a template_fields `foo` in my custom operator, and `foo` is assigned value from reading a file. When it is shown in airflow rendered template, all escape chars are shown like

```
'    select\n'
 "        'v1' as k1,\n"
 "        'v2' as k2,\n"
 "        '2023-05-27' as ds\n"
 "    '''\n"
 '\n'
```

Is there a way to unescape?

Thanks